# If tag in template does not cooperate with boolean passed in context

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a view `login()`:

```
from django.http import HttpRequest
from useraccounts.models import BadIP
def login(request):
    client_address = request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']
    client_instance = BadIP.objects.get(ip_address=client_address)
    if client_instance.ban_state == True:
        return render(request, 'login.html', {'banned':True})
    else:
        return render(request, 'login.html', {'banned':False})
```

And a template:

```
{% if banned == False %}
  <p>Content</p>
{% endif %}

{% if banned == True %}
  <p>Content #2</p>
{% endif %}
```

Under these standards, neither of the two paragraphs will be rendered in the template. However, if I change the instances in the code where `True` and `False` appear to strings, suddenly the template renders fine. Why does this happen, and is there any way to change this behavior to be more obvious/semantically correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are boolean variables already! No need to compare to them `True` or `False`. Try this:

```
{% if banned %}
    <p>Content</p>
{% else %}
    <p>Content #2</p>
{% end if %}
```